# With Glimpse How To Turn It Off Without Disabling?

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

I love Glimpse but only when I' interested in what it has to tell me.  I have a glimpse role that I can turn on and off to make glimpse go away (see code below) but what I really want is to be able to turn it on and off while it is enabled in my global.asax.  I've tried going to site.com/glimpse.axd and set "turn glimpse off" but then on the next page refresh it is back.

What am I missing?

```
public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy : IRuntimePolicy
{
    public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
    {
        var httpContext = policyContext.GetHttpContext();
        if (!httpContext.User.IsInRole("GlimpseUser"))
        {
            return RuntimePolicy.Off;
        }
        return RuntimePolicy.On;
    }

    public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn
    {
        get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest; }
    }
}
```

In My Web.Config:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<runtimePolicies>
  <ignoredTypes>
    <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    <add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy, Glimpse.Core" />
  </ignoredTypes>
</runtimePolicies>
```

Comment: Could you add some more context to what you mean with "enabled in my global.asax" and "next page refresh it is back". Because even without your custom security policy (which  looks fine), after pressing the "Turn Glimpse Off" button, no data should be collected and the Glimpse panel should not be shown. I've written a [blog post](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/12/09/protect-glimpse-axd-with-your-custom-runtime-policy/) a couple of months ago explaining how those runtime policies are being applied at runtime, maybe that might help you.

Comment: I'm showing my global.asax so that comment is not really necessary.  The issue is that with this code running and the user is in the GlimpseUser role, I can not seem to make Glimpse go away.  When I browse to the glimpse.axd page, click on the button turn glimpse off, then do a page refresh, glimpse is still showing on the bottom as if I had not turned it off.

Comment: I'm not quite following there regarding the global.asax, as the only thing I see here is the GlimpseSecurityPolicy. Do you by any chance have an ignoreType entry in the web.config for the CookieControlPolicy, which would result in the Turn Glimpse Off action to be ignored? Did you enable Glimpse logging and noticed something strange in the logs?

Comment: I updated my post with what I have in my web.config re Glimpse.  The other code public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy" in in my global.asax but either VS or resharper is saying it is never used (I don't always believe that though). Obviously, I'm a glimpse beginner at configuration and I should spend more time reading and studying how it is configured.  sorry for being obtuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the reason why clicking on the "Turn Glimpse Off" button has no effect is because the `ControlCookiePolicy` is disabled in the config, hence clicking that button will have no effect.

So you need to remove that entry from the config to make that work again:

```
<add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy, Glimpse.Core" />
```

when you are saying that

> > The other code public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy" is in my global.asax

you mean that the `GlimpseSecurityPolicy` is basically defined as an inner class of the `Mvc Application` class?

Either way if you would enable logging for Glimpse in the config

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <logging level="Trace" />
    <runtimePolicies>
    <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </ignoredTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

then you should see a `glimpse.log` file appear in the root of your web application, and once the application is started, you should see an entry like this:

> > 2014-06-13 09:48:25.8498 | DEBUG | Discovered IRuntimePolicy of type 'SOME NAMESPACE+GlimpseSecurityPolicy' and added it to collection. |

If that is the case then the policy is actually discovered. 
You can put a breakpoint inside the `Execute` method to check whether a call is actually made and what the outcome is.

Comment: Thanks, removing the ignore cookie policy solved it as you said it would.  I'm liking glimpse 1000% better now that I can turn it on and off without having to enable and disable roles.  Keep up the great work!

Comment: I'm glad it is working now. Just keep in mind that from a security point of view, the custom runtime policy that checks for role membership is the way to go than relying on a simple cookie that basically everybody can set (in case you would use it outside a local development machine)